# How to plot in 3D using rxplot

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to plot in 3D using "`rxplot -M 3d`". Here are the steps I do:

```
roscore
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key
rxplot -M 3d /turtle1/pose/x /turtle1/pose/y
```

rxplot gives the following error:

> rxplot: error: You may only specific 2
> or 3 topics with '3d' or 'scatter'.
> When 2 topics are provided, time is used as the third axis.

These commands lead to the same error:

```
rxplot -M 3d /turtle1/pose/x:y
rxplot -M 3d /turtle1/pose/x,/turtle1/pose/y
```

Using three topics doesn't work either.

Using rxplot with option "`-M 2d`" works fine.

Can anyone give me a working example of how to plot in 3D?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9830/how-to-plot-in-3d-using-rxplot/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2011-04-27

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's an open bug on this that I need to resolve first:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3376

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-05-21**:
For the record: This bug has been fixed long time ago and my turtlesim example from the question works now.